# How to pass the wrong value to my request header and assert error message from it

Tags: junit, request-headers

I have to do a unit testing of my servlet by passing the wrong request headers and parameters and getting failure message printed in the console

I have used Mockito framework

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your servlet is not third-party but created by you. That means you shouldn't need the mockito for starters ( except of course if you want to mock everything after your servlet ) .

Second. Lets say your servlet accepts APPLICATION-JSON and you send STREAM-OCTET. Shouldn't that return ( response ) the appropriate http error? If you agree with that then asserting the response itself to see if it is the expected http status. ( for example 400 which is bad_request the appropriate response for wrong headers. )

If you want to "hide" the error by returning OK#200 for all the requests you can get a hold of the logger by either injection or reflection ( the first way is preferable ) and parse the output. Printing on the System.out/System.err would be a lot tricker to get a hold of but printing errors there is not a good practice either. But now, if you "hide" the mistake on the headers then your client would never be able to guess what went wrong!